# UNIX alternative for two functions in pstat on HPUX

Tags: linux, hp-ux

We are moving a project from HP-UX to Redhar Linux.
We have a problem with library pstat which only exists on HP-UX.
We are looking for a replacement for two functions that call functions in pstat library.

1. Function 1: look whether a command 'cmd' is beeing executed by some user 'usr'
   parameter              : p1-cmd, p2-user 
   return code            : 0   -  cmd is *not* running, >0  -  cmd is running = pid !!
2. Function 2: look whether a processID 'pid' is beeing executed by some user 'usr'
   parameter              : p1-pid, p2-user
   return code            : 0   -  cmd is running , 1   -  cmd is not running

Any help would be appreciated.

Best Regards
Arthur

Comment: http://procps.sourceforge.net/